# Emoji doesn't show in NSAttributedString when typed using iOS keyboard, does when typed on Android

Tags: android, ios, nsattributedstring, utf-16, emoji

I'm making a messenging application and when I send an emoji from the Android side, it shows fine on the iOS side, yet the iOS side cannot (it seems) display emojis from iOS's own keyboard!

The label in which I am showing the emoji uses attributed text and the text comes from HTML. The following code is used to generate the NSAttributedString

```
var msg = getTextForDisplay()//Essentially gets the plain text
msg = "<span style=\"font-family: Helvetica; font-size:14pt;\">" + msg + "</span>"
if let data = msg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false){
    let attributed = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType ], documentAttributes: nil)
    return attributed
}
```

Even stranger, when I send the emoji from iOS, although it doesn't show in the label as described above, it does show on the Android side perfectly fine. On the iOS side, in the label, it shows what appears to be jibberish (unicode chasracters perhaps?)

eg: [image]

I am absolutely sure the error is with the displaying of the emoji, because when printed to console, I see real emoji and also when saved to the device storage and later read on a Mac, it is real emoji. But when the emoji is loaded into the attributed label, it shows jibberish

Any help is appreciated. I understand the issue is something to do with encoding I'm just not sure what exactly the problem is and how to fix it

Comment: Please share the 'getTextForDisplay' function too. There's lots of things that can go wrong when converting to/from various text formats, especially if you're passing around using JSON.

Comment: @Ben It literally returns a String with plain text, eg "Hello"

Comment: Just a hardcoded string, or a string imported from somewhere else?

Comment: @Ben Imported. It could be almost anything but I've tried it with known strings and it doesn't work. I'll post some example strings and outputs in about an hour

Comment: @Ben Adding the following line print("GET TEXT FOR DISPLAY " + msg) in the method prints this: "GET TEXT FOR DISPLAY "

Comment: @Ben also showing the emoji without HTML formatting and without using attributed text works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We verified in the comments that the source string is okay. There's just one single parameter to change! Swift usually uses **UTF-16** for strings. You're losing information processing it as UTF-8.

Change:

msg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding

To:

msg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF**16**StringEncoding

**For swift 5:** use this `msg.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false)`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Strange I didn't think of that because I made the same mistake in another part of the app