# How to show an HTML string with emoji on a UILabel in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I want show HTML string with emoji in `UILabel` and i have created this code for show HTML content and now i want to show emoji also, anyone can help me?

```
func stringFromHtml(string: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        if let d = data {
            let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)

            return str
        }
    } catch { }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: What's the emoji? Real emoji (with the correct code https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)? Or something like `:p` that you want to convert? An external image? Do you have sample of the HTML string?

Comment: similar question i think https://stackoverflow.com/a/33246927/14206959

Answer (score 0):

Use utf16 instead of utf8. Try the following code:

```
func stringFromHtml(string: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: true)
        if let d = data {
            let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)

            return str
        }
    } catch { }
    return nil
}
```